# Capitalize first letter in form input - Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to ensure the first letter of each word is capitalized in a form submission.

```
@csrf
<div class="form-group">
<label for="group_title">Group Title:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="group_title" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="group_description">Group Description:</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="group_description"></textarea>
</div>

<!-- Date picker -->
<div class="form-group">
<label for="group_date">Group Date:</label>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control" name="group_date" autocomplete="off" />
</div>

<!-- Time -->
<div class="form-group">
<label for="group_time">Group Time:</label>
<input type="time" class="form-control" name="group_time" />
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Group</button>
</form>
```

This is actually a Laravel specific question which has now been answered below.

Comment: I think you should be doing the capitalisation at the server, rather than the client side of your code.

Comment: if you want to capitalize at client, [this](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/input-field-uppercase/) may help.

Comment: `ucfirst( strtolower( $_POST['group_title'] ) )`?

Comment: are you using a framework ?

Comment: @RamRaider 'group title' is only one of the fields, I've edited my question to show the full form.  I can't add POST to the whole form because I only need the 'title' to be capitalised so should I do this ```ucfirst( strtolower( <label for="group_title">Group Title:</label> ) )```?

Comment: @ Mohammed Yassine CHABLI  Yes, I use Laravel 6

Comment: @Dragonthoughts agreed, I want the capitalisation at the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `ucfirst` from PHP

For example

```
{{ ucfirst(trans('messages.yourMessage')) }}
```

Comment: They should use `ucwords()` if they need to capitalize each word. Also it might be better to use `mb_convert_case()` if they are using multibyte encoding.

Comment: Ok, to be clear, I show the title on a public page like this ```{{ $group->group_title }}``` and it's this title which needs to have capital first letters. So, should I edit that code to be ```{{ $group->group_title }} echo ucfirst($string);```??

Comment: which one is the variable that needs the first letter to be uppercase?

Comment: @PHP75DJ also you just said that you re using HTML and PHP so I gave you a solution in PHP.
If you're using something else you should specify it.
By the way just search on google for make first leter uppercase and add the programming language you need.
I ensure you 200% there will be 300 pages at least telling you how to do that

Comment: @Synapsis  I use PHP with Laravel framework. I've tried Google but can't get it to work, I am new to coding. It's the ```group_title``` which needs capitals.

Comment: if you're using laravel then use this code: {{ ucfirst(trans('messages.yourMessageToDisplay')) }}

Answer (score 1):

**In Css**:
If we use capitalize a word that's in all capital letters already, the other letters in the word won't switch to lowercase.

**In php**:
The ucwords() function converts the first character of each word in a string to uppercase.

```
echo ucwords("hello world"); //converts the first character of a string to uppercase
```